# Vim: Open current windows/tabs in GVim instead

Tags: vim, gvim

Let's say I have been working in a given Vim session for some time, and come to a point where I *really* would like to have everything I am looking at in **GVim** instead.

The actual use-case is a terminal Vim session with a large number of windows... I'd like to click-activate them instead of going through Ctrl-W each time, something that can be done in GVim but not Vim (not mine, at least).

Is there a way to take the buffers / windows / tabs currently open in Vim, and open them in GVim instead?

Comment: All nice and well, but completely unnecessary to solve the actual use-case problem: `set mouse=a` activates mouse support for terminal Vim as well, making Vim windows click-activateable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `:gui` command to open the current session in GVim.

See `:help :gui` for the gory details.

Comment: I actually found Ingo's answer to be more helpful overall, as I didn't know about sessions and could see where they can be useful outside the scope of my actual question. But you did *answer* the actual question more precisely, so I feel you should get the checkmark of honor.

Answer (score 5):

That's what *sessions* are for. In terminal Vim, you save your current setup via `:mksession Session.vim`, quit Vim, and then launch GVIM with that session: `$ gvim -S Session.vim`.

You can influence what gets persisted via `'sessionoptions'`. I'd recommend to remove storing the mappings, that reduces the session size significantly: `:set sessionoptions-=options`. Also, there are plugins like [session.vim - Extended session management for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) that simplify the handling.

Comment: So simple, yet so powerful. I don't think I will ever stop being amazed by Vim. Thanks!